# NULL value when post ajax curl php

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, curl, php-curl

Why always NULL value data from Ajax with CURL method in codeigniter?

Here is my error:

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 23000/515 [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'noreg', table 'DBRS_MARGONO.dbo.VKLAIM_VERIF'; column does not
>   allow nulls. INSERT fails. INSERT INTO "VKLAIM_VERIF" ("noreg",
>   "user_id", "verified", "level_verif", "catatan") VALUES (NULL, NULL,
>   NULL, 0, '') Filename:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/ws/system/database/DB_driver.php Line Number: 691

and here are my controller to print when ajax is called:

```
$post = array();
        $post['noreg'] = $this->input->post('noreg');
        $post['user'] = $this->input->post('user');
        $post['status'] = $this->input->post('verified');

        $url = 'http://localhost/ws/rsms/verifupdatesimpanstatus';

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "X-API-Key: " . $aksesws['X-API-Key'],
            "IDAPP: " . $aksesws['IDAPP'])
        );

        $de = curl_exec($ch);
        $d = json_decode($de, true);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $de;
```

But when I test my post data `$post` is sent and I think the problem in CURL POST method. I have been searching solutions and I don't know where is the error. Web service works well when I test it in Postman with **POST** method **x-www-form-urlencoded**

Here are my ajax code:

```
function updateStatusVerif(noreg,user,verified) {
        $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>superuser/pasien/updateStatusVerif",
        {
            noreg : noreg,
            user : user,
            verified : verified
        },
        function(data){
            $('#btnverif').html(data);
        });
    }
```

I send return data value from web service to #btnverif element.

Comment: After you add values to the $post do a json_encode and try to send that via postman, see what happens.

Comment: did you mean use raw instead x-www-form-urlencoded in postman ? so I send data to web service with json format?

Comment: @Arthur wow bingooo, it works, thanks so much sir

Answer (score 0):

after help from @Arthur I add `json_encode` to `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);` thanks you #SOLVED